# textBoxName.Text isn't getting the text entered by user, only the text that was set there on load

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox

I have this textbox:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDescription" runat="server" Height="90%" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="90%"></asp:TextBox>
```

and I set its' text value:

```
description = reader["Description"].ToString();
txtDescription.Text = description;
```

This is for editing the "description" so I have the existing description in the box and then want to get the text that is in the box at the end as it has been altered.

However I do:

```
 string newDecription = txtDescription.Text;
```

and the value is that which it was initially set as. The above code to get the text value is ran on a submit button, so isn't somehow running and getting the value before it has been edited.

CONTEXT

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        getValues();
    }
string ID = 1;
protected void getValues()
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
        using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("SELECT Name,Stock,Price250g,Price1kg,Description,StockOrdered FROM Stock WHERE id = @ID", conn))
        {
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", ID);
            conn.Open();
            using (SqlDataReader reader = comm.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    price250g = reader["Price250g"].ToString();
                    price1kg = reader["Price1kg"].ToString();
                    name = reader["Name"].ToString();
                    description = reader["Description"].ToString();
                    stock = reader["Stock"].ToString();
                    stockOrdered = Convert.ToBoolean(reader["StockOrdered"].ToString());

                    lblName.Text = name;
                    lbl250g.Text += price250g.Remove(price250g.Length - 2);
                    lbl1kg.Text += price1kg.Remove(price1kg.Length - 2);
                    lblStock.Text = stock + "g";
                    cbStockOrdered.Checked = stockOrdered;
                    txtDescription.Text = description;
                }
            }
        }
    }


private void addAddressToOrder()
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Stock SET Name=@name, Stock=@stock, Price250g=@price250, Price1kg=@price1kg, Description=@description, StockOrdered=@ordered WHERE Id=@ID", conn))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", ID);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@description", txtDescription.Text);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", txtName.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@price250", txtPrice250g.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@price1kg", txtPrice1kg.Text);

            stock = ddAddStock.SelectedValue + stock;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stock", stock);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ordered", cbStockOrdered.Checked);

            conn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }

    protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        addAddressToOrder();
        Response.Redirect("~/Admin/AdminHome.aspx");
    }
```

Comment: One page, runs at the onload getting the info to display. Then on same page I get the value on in a method via button click. I do the exact same for other pieces of info on the same page, description is the only one I fill the textbox with data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This commonly happens when you do this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // other code
    txtDescription.Text = description;
}
```

The reason is because of the [page lifecycle events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472(v=vs.100).aspx).  `Page_Load` executes *every time* the page is loaded.  This includes post-backs.  (After all, you need to load the page in order to interact with it.)  And it runs *before* any button handlers or other similar control events.  So if this code, which writes a value to the text box, is executing before you read a value from the text box then it's going to overwrite that value.

Any code in `Page_Load` (or similar page initialization events) which shouldn't run on post-backs needs to be wrapped in a conditional:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        // other code
        txtDescription.Text = description;
    }
}
```

Comment: I've not heard of post back before, but nothing on the page causes the page to  essentially reload or anything. OnLoad just gets the values and pops it in the text box. Then theres the button method to get the value from the textbox.

Comment: On the same page I have textboxes that I don't populate onload, and I get the values the same way I do for the description textbox and they return entered values and not null/string.empty etc which is their value onLoad.

Comment: @Tom: Without seeing more context it's impossible to say for certain.  But clearly something is overwriting the value before you read it.  In the vast majority of cases, it's happening in `Page_Load`.  You say that you populate the values when the page loads, and you say that you've never heard of this conditional check before, so it seems *highly likely* that this is the problem.

Comment: @Tom: Yes, this is *exactly* what's happening.  Your Page_Load is overwriting the controls' values on post-back.  Use the conditional check to fix it.

Comment: Thanks, caused some bumps with variables in other methods on the page, but got it to work thank you :) Now I know post Back is a thing.